# ajax jquery with bookmarklet troubles with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, localhost, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet set up. I have alerts throughout the page to check my codes, and for some reason my ajax is not working. It works great on localhost, but when I'm testing on external sites, it fails

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/sites.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: "site_url="+urlValue  
}).error(function(){
    alert("error");
}).done(function(data){
   alert("inside ajax");
   //some coding

});
```

This script works in localhost, but it doesn't work on external sites. Why is that? is it because the url is localhost? But I've tested some other localhost scripts on external sites and it works. For instance I've inserted CSS scripts with a localhost URL `http://127.0.0.1/css/sample.css` and placed it into external sites and the CSS styling works.

Comment: It would work only on the server this file comes from. Are you trying to access XYZ.com while your file loads from ABC.com (localhost) ?

Comment: This violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: @Thrustmaster I'm trying to access ABC.com (localhost) from XYZ.com. For instance, I add alerts before $.ajax and it alerts. so I'm just trying to access another file within the file $.ajax resides in.

Comment: @Musa is there another method of doing such thing? In the end, I'm trying to do something what pinterest is doing? However, I'm trying to pass parameters into a php script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This violates the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Read up on CORS http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

At the beginning of sites.php before any output is sent add this

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

use `*` to specify any site since its a bookmarlet.

Comment: can you explain how I maybe able to implement this into my jquery script? Thanks

Comment: `sites.php` is an external site that I don't have control of. Its just a random site though? Is there a way to use jquery to insert the header to `sites.php`? Thanks!

Comment: @andrewliu well that's the whole point of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), to prevent people from messing around with other peoples sites

Comment: so cors wouldn't be the way for me? I'm trying to do what pinterest does. But I'm not sure their method of doing it. I'm just trying to use ajax to call some data, but i'm not messing any data up on the external site.

Comment: maybe there's a way to use jquery to insert that header into the site?

Comment: @andrewliu you just mixed me up there, you are putting the code in your `http://127.0.0.1/sites.php`

Comment: I have a bookmarklet-> user clicks on it when they're at some random site-> the bookmarklet is associated to `ABC.js` (my .js file from my server. In `ABC.js` it has `$.ajax({...})` which is the script above. Then its calling `sites.php` from my server also. I hope that cleared things up?

Comment: I inserted into `sites.php`, but i'm still getting error alert

Comment: Yeah thats what I did. I added that to the `sites.php` and I'm getting the alert error that I have in ajax

Comment: OH WAIT! IT WORKED! I had forgotten I added a dataType, to try different solutions! it worked!! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'external' url, are your referring to a web site other than the one this page is running on?  If so, my initial thought is that you're running into a security restriction with ajax calls.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If you try to make an ajax call to a remote server, it will execute without an error, but the response will come back totally blank.  The browser won't allow you to use the response to do anything.  I seem to recall being frustrated by it because neither the success or the error events trigger, since there's *nothing* for jQuery to make a decision on.

You're going to need to put the sites.php on your same site, or create a local php page that fetches the remote file.  If you do this, then your ajax call can retrieve the remote file locally from your php script.

Here's some code that we use to proxy ajax calls with UltraCart:
(We're not a php shop, so I would **love** some suggestions on how to improve it.)
We install it on the local machine, and use it to proxy our ajax calls.

```
<?php

$server_get_url = "https://www.myremoteserver.com/somepage.php"; 
$post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

foreach($_SERVER as $i=>$val) {  
    if (strpos($i, 'HTTP_') === 0) {  
        $name = str_replace(array('HTTP_', '_'), array('', '-'), $i);  
        $header[$name] = $val;  
    }  
}

$header[] = "Content-Length: ". strlen($post_data);

$ch = curl_init( $server_get_url ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

if ( strlen($post_data)>0 ){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);     

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print curl_error($ch);
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
// our page returns back json ... you may need to adjust this.
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: I may remember wrong then. Sorry. Do you have firebug for FireFox?  If so, open the console and watch the request.  I recall that those requests which were in violation will have a blank response ... or they were colored red.

Comment: save the php file above.  We name ours proxy.php.  Edit the $server_get_url and point it to your external file.  Then change your ajax to point to the proxy.php script.  It'll take you about 5 minutes and will let you know if this is the problem.